# ValueError: Can't handle mix of unknown and binary

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis, multinomial

i have recently used scikit-learn for sentiment analysis, so after i have trained my labeled data then tried to test them on unlabeled set of data, this error comes up 'ValueError: Can't handle mix of continuous-multioutput and binary'

i think that what i am doing wrong is that i give the (y_pred) the wrong assumption.

the error comes from this: accuracy = classifier.score(test_matrix,ALL_test)

but when i change the ALL_test to ALL_train (trained and labeled data) it brings the accuracy of 0.971251409245; which is absolutely wrong

what should i do?

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import sklearn.cross_validation
import sklearn.feature_extraction.text
import sklearn.metrics
import sklearn.naive_bayes
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score


name = ['Tweet','Label']
name2 =['Tweet','Label']
data_train = pd.read_table('unstemmedtrain.csv',sep = ';',names = name)
data_test = pd.read_table('unstemmedtest.csv',names=name2)
train_data =pd.DataFrame(data_test,columns=name2)
test_data=pd.DataFrame(data_train,columns=name)

vectorizer =  sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer()

train_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data['Tweet'])
test_matrix = vectorizer.transform(test_data['Tweet'])
#print train_matrix

positive_train = (train_data['Label']=='positive')
negative_train= (train_data['Label']=='negative')
neutral_train=(train_data['Label']=='neutral')
#print negative_cases_train
ALL_train = positive_train +negative_train +neutral_train
#print positive_cases_train
ALL_test = (test_data['Tweet'])
positive_test =(test_data['Label']=='positive')
negative_test =(test_data['Label']=='negative')
neutral_test = (test_data['Label']=='neutral')
ALL_Test = positive_test + negative_test + neutral_test

#print positive_cases_test


classifier=sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB()
classifier2 = classifier.fit(train_matrix,ALL_train)

p_sentiment = classifier.predict(test_matrix)
p_prob = classifier.predict_proba(test_matrix)
#print predicted_prob
accuracy = classifier.score(test_matrix,ALL_test)
print accuracy
```

Comment: Which classifier are you using?
Can you provide a usable (but minimal) code example?

Comment: Naive Bayes Multinomial,

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues here.

1. Are you trying to predict which tweet is positive, which is negative and which is neutral, or are you trying to predict if a tweet is positive/negative/neutral or not? You're doing the latter. let's assume `train_data['Label'] = ['positive', 'positive', 'negative', 'neutral']`. So your code does:

   ```
   positive_train = (train_data['Label']=='positive') # = [True, True, False, False]
   negative_train= (train_data['Label']=='negative') # = [False, False, True, False]
   neutral_train=(train_data['Label']=='neutral') # = [False, False, False, True]
   ALL_train = positive_train +negative_train +neutral_train # = [True, True, True, True]
   ```
2. You're giving the score function `ALL_test = (test_data['Tweet'])` which is text, and not `ALL_Test = positive_test + negative_test + neutral_test` which is your real y. That's where the exception comes from. I don't know why you need `All_test`, but if you do, name it differently - it's confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass All_train to classifier.score

As:

```
accuracy = classifier.score(test_matrix,ALL_train)
print accuracy
```

If you want to evaluate your model for test data then Recall,precision,f1 score and auc_score may help